# Regex match expected but not matching

Tags: regex, pcre, substitution

Given this string of `;` delimited values

```
a;; z
toy;d;hh 
toy
;b;;jj
z;
d;23
d;23td
;;io;
b y;b;12
z
a;b;bb;;;34
z
```

and this regex

```
^(?!([^\r\n;]*);(?:(b|d))(?:;|$)).*\R
```

I am looking to get the full lines whose 2nd. column is not `b` or `d`, and have the matching lines removed, like this

```
toy;d;hh 
;b;;jj
b y;b;12
a;b;bb;;;34
```

Please see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/v6YjNB/1)

Line 13's second column is not `b` or `d`. Still, it does not match and it shows in the substitution box.

Line 11 has the same string and it does match.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're looking for a new line sequence `\R` that doesn't exist at the end of the last line.

using one the following can fix the issue:

`^(?!([^\r\n;]*);(?:(b|d))(?:;|$)).*\R*`

`^(?!([^\r\n;]*);(?:(b|d))(?:;|$)).*(\R|$)`

`^(?!([^\r\n;]*);(?:(b|d))(?:;|$)).*\R{0,1}`

## What Chnaged?

`\R*` will match zero OR more new line sequences

`\R{0,1}` will match zero OR one new line sequence

`(\R|$)` will match a new line sequence OR end of line